# Can't run fxml app using Intellij and 1.8 JDK

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following very simple app

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;

public class Controller {
    public TextField theight;
    public TextField tweight;


    public Label lbmi;
    public Label lresult;


    public void buttonclicked(){

        double height;
        double weight;
        double bmi;

        String result;


        height = Double.parseDouble(theight.getText());
        weight = Double.parseDouble(tweight.getText());

        double square = height * height;
        bmi = weight / square;
        lbmi.setText("The BMI is " + bmi);
    }
}
```

and sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="210.0" text="BMI Calculator" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
         <font>
            <Font size="29.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="theight" alignment="CENTER" promptText="Enter your height in meters" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="tweight" alignment="CENTER" promptText="Enter your weight in kg" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonclicked" text="Calculate" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Label fx:id="lbmi" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="280.0" text="Your BMI will be displayed here" textOverrun="CLIP" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Label fx:id="lresult" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="211.0" text="What your BMI means" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

I have figured out that the controller was not added by default and added it as fx:controller="sample.Controller". However, I still get an error:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/JAVA/BMIC/out/production/BMIC/sample/sample.fxml:30
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller class you are importing `awt` classes for `TextField` and `Label`. Import the javafx classes.

**Edit:**

You have to remove the awt imports and insert the javafx imports:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
    public TextField theight;
    public TextField tweight;


    public Label lbmi;
    public Label lresult;


    public void buttonclicked() {

        double height;
        double weight;
        double bmi;

        String result;


        height = Double.parseDouble(theight.getText());
        weight = Double.parseDouble(tweight.getText());

        double square = height * height;
        bmi = weight / square;
        lbmi.setText("The BMI is " + bmi);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do it? import java.javafx.*; does not work.

Comment: import javafx.*; it is displayed as unused import statement. Maybe, the problem is in something else?

Comment: @user2742080: your javafx imports are unused because you are importing awt classes, see my updated answer.